# Kestrel configuration to use a specific port + url

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, kestrel-http-server

I am using Asp.Net core 2.0.2 on Win 7 with VS2017 (15.3.5).

My current Kestrel configuration looks like this:

```
return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, config) =>
    {
        var envName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");

        config.Sources.Clear();
        config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional : false);
        config.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{envName}.json", optional : false);
        config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
    })
    .UseKestrel(options =>
    {
        options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5859);
    })
    .UseContentRoot(pathToContentRoot)
    .Build();
```

This obviously listens on `http://localhost:5859`. I want to configure Kestrel so that it ONLY listens on a custom URL such as `http://localhost:5859/MyNewApp`. How do I do that?

(With Core 1.0, I had used `UseUrls("http://localhost:5859/MyNewApp")` which partially did the job. It would listen on `http://localhost:5859` as well as `http://localhost:5859/MyNewApp`. Doing the same in Core 2.0.2 results in an exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: A path base can only be configured using IApplicationBuilder.UsePathBase())

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With 2.0 you need to leverage `UsePathBase` as `UseUrls` was [removed from Kestrel](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/1050). You'll want to do this in your `Configure` method at startup:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UsePathBase("/MyNewApp"); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it works fine! Is there a way I can restrict application to not work on http://localhost:5859? At present, both localhost:5859 and localhost:5859/MyNewApp work.

Comment: Kestel is more of an App Server than a full Web Server. Generally, you use a full-service web server such as IIS or Apache to sit between the internet and your app and proxy incoming calls. This post has a good explanation of how this works and why it's a good thing: https://stackify.com/kestrel-web-server-asp-net-core-kestrel-vs-iis/